# Boolean methods with an ArrayList that stores Objects with multiple fields

Tags: java

I need help creating a boolean method. I am creating a stock exchange type system in which the highest proposed price from a person will buy the stock.

I have an arraylist of an object which includes the person (Person class) and the proposed price (priceVal double). This object is called PerPrice.

I also have a method to return the highest price out of the list of objects

```
public Compete getHighestPrice() {

Collections.sort(compete);

PerPri highestPrice = null;

if(!this.compete.isEmpty()) {
  highestPrice = this.compete.get(this.compete.size()-1);
}

return highestPrice;

}
```

This works as the Collection.sort works with a compareTo method in the PerPri class which sorts compares the value of the priceVal double within the object. Sorting it so that the last in the index will be the highestPrice

So I want the boolean method to be able to create a successful sell as true, if it's only object in the list, or if it has a higher priceValue than the previous object. Otherwise I want it to return false naturally.

I will also attatch the code below that I'm using to return an order which puts the highest value last (In the PerPri class)

```
@Override
public int compareTo(PerPri perpri) {
//Comparison constants.
final int EQUAL = 0;
int result = EQUAL;

// Check if the two objects are the same
if (this == prepri) {
  result = EQUAL;
}

else {

  int priceValueOrder = Double.compare(this.getPriceValue(), perpri.getPriceValue());

  if (result == EQUAL) {
    result = priceValueOrder;
  }
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear to me. What do you mean with "boolean method" -- where do you need this? Or, is there currently just a problem with the `compareTo()` implementation? I don't think we have enough information to know what is a "successful sell". Maybe adding the source for `PerPri` could help.

Comment: All I wanted a successful sell to be (at this point) was that if the `priceValue` of one of the objects was higher than the previous in the ArrayList. (to return true)

Comment: That's trivial: `return compete.get(compete.size()-1).compareTo(compete.get(compete.size()-2)) > 0;`

Comment: @DodgyCodeException If you have an answer, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Usually, it's more effective to re-calculate statistics on update/write only than to do it on each call of get. So, typical pattern in order book modelling is to insert each new price/order in already ordered list. Think about adding each price/order to TreeSet using a Comparator on price. And remember about the difference between best bid and offer prices